# java.lang.IllegalStateException onCreate activity in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, networking, dialog, illegalstateexception

i've published an android app (made with Xamarin.Android), and some users had a crash. I can't reproduce it. It happens only on Android 8.0.

Reports from Android vitals:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2854)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2933)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:231)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6749)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:997)
at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source:99)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source:10)
at crc64ea360a874f61476c.NetworkActivity.n_onCreate (Native Method)
at crc64ea360a874f61476c.NetworkActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7056)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2807)
```

The Oncreate() looks like this:

```
public class NetworkActivity : AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AppCompatActivity
{
    Utils utils;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        utils = new Utils();
    }
}
```

The utils class is used to call a custom dialog.

Any tips?

Thank You.

Regards.